# Bugged sidenav in materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

I created a navbar, the navbar items collapse on small devices and can be seen through pressing a button that shows the items as a sidenav, the issue i'm having is that I'm not able to click any of the links, it shows the sidenav but everything is disabled, I'm going to show the snippet to explain this better.

```html
<!-- This is a free template created by the github user NeutronBlast, please don't erase this -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper teal">
                <!-- Your logo here! -->
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo ml-nav-4 mt-2">L
                </a>

                <!-- Trigger button for collapsible menu on phone view -->
                <a href="#" data-target="menu-responsive" class="sidenav-trigger">
                    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                </a>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">FEATURES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Menu that will be shown on small devices -->
                <ul class="sidenav" id="menu-responsive">
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#features">LINK</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script type="application/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            M.AutoInit();



        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: I realized that removing the div with the class navbar-fixed solves the problem of the sidenav being disabled but I need the navbar to be fixed on desktop, so simply removing that it's not enough of a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to keep the sidenav markup outside of the navbar markup...

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper teal">
            <!-- Your logo here! -->
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo ml-nav-4 mt-2">L</a>
            <!-- Trigger button for collapsible menu on phone view -->
            <a href="#" data-target="menu-responsive" class="sidenav-trigger">
                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            </a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">FEATURES</a></li>
                ..
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- Menu that will be shown on small devices -->
<ul class="sidenav" id="menu-responsive">
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#features">LINK</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

https://codeply.com/p/IsB0HvAEJy